# Assigning mean values of a numpy row to a variable to use for making a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, graph

Sorry for yet another question but I'm very new at python.

I have reaction time data for my go/no go conditions. I have put them into a dictionary called rts and split with two keys (go) and (no-go). I have worked out how to separate each numpy array row within these conditions as each row is a participant (there are 20 participants). I've managed to print out the mean and standard deviation for each participant into a table. This is the code below:

```
for row in range(0,20):
    go_row=rts["go"][row,:]
    nogo_row=rts["nogo"][row,:]
    participant=row+1
    print ("{}             {:.2f}     {:.2f}        {:.2f}     {:.2f}".format (participant, \
           go_row.mean(), go_row.std(),nogo_row.mean(), nogo_row.std()))
```

What I'm struggling to do is make a variable with each of the mean values for each participant. I want to do this as I want to create a histogram showing the distribution in performance across participants. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what you are looking for is a way to collect all of the information you are printing as something you can loop over later and analyze, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want `list`

```
means_participant = []

for row in range(0,20):
    go_row=rts["go"][row,:]
    nogo_row=rts["nogo"][row,:]
    participant=row+1

    means_participant.append(go_row.mean())
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the values for each row in a dictionary, then add the dictionaries to a list that can be looped over later. This can be condensed, but I left it spelled out for clarity.

```
values = []

for row in range(0,20):
    go_row=rts["go"][row,:]
    nogo_row=rts["nogo"][row,:]
    participant=row+1
    d = {}
    d['participant'] = participant
    d['go_row_mean'] = go_row.mean()
    d['go_row_std'] = go_row.std()
    d['nogo_row_mean'] = nogo_row.mean()
    d['nogo_row_std'] = nogo_row.std()
    values.append(d)
```

The dictionary would be unnecessary if you know you only want one of the values, such as the `go_row.mean()`, and if you didn't care about matching the means in the list back up with a participant.